# How do I instantiate a variable in C++ only once?

Tags: c++, static

In Java, static variables are only instantiated only once and behave like global variables.

In terms of efficiency and speed, is there a way to do this in C++?
Since static, in C++, blocks don't exist.

If there's a constant like Foo = 17, and I'm making multiple instances of the class, how do I keep the constant from being instantiated that many times?

Would the same syntax apply to structs too?

Comment: What's the problem with [`static`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) ?

Comment: "Since static, in C++, blocks don't exist" -- that's where you are wrong.  `static` works at global level, on class member variables, and inside blocks (which are usually function bodies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same way. You might have a function that you'd like to keep track of the number of times the function is called throughout the life of the program, well it's as easy as...

```
int foo()
{
   static int times = 0;
   ...
   return times;
}
```

Pretty pointless but nonetheless it does what you're describing.  You can do the same thing in a class.

```
class myClass 
{
   public:
   static int many;
   ...
   int getMany() { return many; }
};
```

Here the function always returns the number of instances that exist.

Comment: Is the memory allocated by the static variables the same address for all instances of myClass too?

Comment: @WCGPR0: It's not even part of an instance, it's part of the class.  It exists even when there are no instances at all.

Comment: Oh your right. I was just originally under the impression unlike Java, static statements gets executed multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same keyword ie `static` in c/c++
See msdn document [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx).

> The static keyword can be used to declare variables, functions, class
>   data members and class functions. By default, an object or variable
>   that is defined outside all blocks has static duration and external
>   linkage. Static duration means that the object or variable is
>   allocated when the program starts and is deallocated when the program
>   ends. External linkage means that the name of the variable is visible
>   from outside the file in which the variable is declared. Conversely,
>   internal linkage means that the name is not visible outside the file
>   in which the variable is declared.